# Android Service with "ongoing notification" as well as One off notification stops working when I open activity with ongoing notification

Tags: android, service, notifications

So I am having a small problem with creating notifications that open an activity from a service. I have narrowed the problem down to what appears to be a conflict between the "ongoing" pending intent and the "notification" pending intent.

So let me describe what I am trying to do.

I have an application that has a background service polling for new data from a data server. The app continues to poll for data even when there is no activity in focus to allow the app to notify the user of specific events. (similar to having a background service poll for new mail every 10 minutes).

I want the user to always be aware that the app is running as the polling does risk the users data plan if the app if forgotten about. For this reason I created an "ongoing" notification in the service's onCreate function. When the user taps on the ongoing notification The service should either bring the main app activity to the front or create one. This is done using the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    // the Data object is the actual polling object runnable
    data = new Data();
    // ui and data intents are used to send data from the service to the activities that need them
    ui_intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    data_intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);

    res = getResources();

    // the intent to start the main activity
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Spectrum.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Notification notification = new Notification(
            R.drawable.notification_icon, "", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "App Name", "Open App",
            contentIntent);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    startForeground(APP_NOTIFICATION, notification);
}
```

So far this code works fine. If i press the home button and then tap on the ongoing notification it brings up the main activity (Spectrum.class)

Now on top of the ongoing notification I also want specific event notifications that occur from time to time. When a user taps on one of these notifications the app is to create a new spectrum layer and pass some information to that activity to display. (again very similar to a mail app that starts the main program and highlights the new email).

To create these notifications I use the following code
        private void alert(int alert_id)
    {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        String name = data.getData()[alert_id];

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
    CharSequence tickerText = name + " has an event";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "New Event!";
    CharSequence contentText = name;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Spectrum.class);

    notificationIntent.putExtra(Spectrum.CURRENT_IDX, alert_id);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())
            .getBoolean("vibrate", false))
    {
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    }
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())
            .getBoolean("chirp", false))
    {
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    }

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, alert_id,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
            contentIntent);
    // I want multiple alerts, up to 1 for every event id so simply set the
    // notification id to be the event id.
    mNotificationManager.notify(alert_id, notification);
}
```

Again this code works fine. When the event occurs the notification is displayed. If the notification is tapped the spectrum activity is created and the intent extas are processed correctly. More specifically I have tested it with multiple events being created and tapping them in various orders and everything works perfectly

The problem comes when I press the home button, bring the app back to the front with the ongoing notification and then try to tap one of the event notifications. As soon as I have pressed the ongoing notification the event notifications stop working. They are still created and when I tap on them they are cleared but no new spectrum activity is created and the data being passed (event_id) is not processed. (the previous activity stays the same).

Does anyone know why the event notifications stop working?

One thing I have noticed is that prior to tapping on the ongoing service notification when I tap on an event notification I get an Info message int he LogCat that looks like

```
10-04 11:39:07.153: W/ActivityManager(102): startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=android.package.test/.Spectrum bnds=[0,369][480,465] (has extras) }
```

but after I have pressed the ongoing service notification i get the above line plus the following line

```
10-04 11:42:44.953: W/InputManagerService(102): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4085c650
```

Edit: forgot to mention that I am coding on a windows machine using eclipse. Compiling against android 3.2, and testing on a physical Nexus One device

Any ideas?